# How to prove that $L = \{w\in\{a,b\}^*\mid w = uav \text{ and } |u| = |v|\}$ is not a regular language

Tags: regular-languages, pumping-lemma

$L = \{w\in\{a,b\}^*\mid w = uav \text{ and } |u| = |v|\}$

I know to use the pump lemma, but I don’t know how to use it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose towards a contradiction that $L$ is regular and let $p$ be its pumping length.
Consider $w = b^pab^p \in L$.
By the pumping lemma there is some integer $1\le i \le p$ such that $b^{p+ki} a b^p \in L$ for all choices of an integer $k \ge -1$.
However, choosing $k=-1$ yields $b^{p-i} a b^p \not\in L$, which provides the sought contradiction.

Comment: I don't know why it can be k>= -1？Is there any basis?

Comment: By the pumping lemma $b^{p-i} (b^i)^h a b^p = b^{ (p-i)+hi } a b^p \in L$ for every integer $h \ge 0$. The integers that can be expressed as $(p-i)+hi$ with $h \ge 0$ are exactly those that can be expressed as $p+ki$ for $k \ge -1$.